# Component button to show 'n' number of div elements initially, then show 'n' number more elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a component class/button that will show 'n' number of div elements initially, then will show 'n' number more elements each time the button is clicked until there are no more div elements to be displayed.

I am using `ASP.NET MVC`, so I have a list of elements coming in to my view and being displayed through a for loop. I have used a jQuery slider component for something else before to display n elements in a row with the given functionality of left/right drag-scroll functionality and click arrows. Will I be able to find a jQuery component or will I have to write my own Javascript?

I have attempted with the following:

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row whiteBG">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
        {
            <div id="special-products" class="col-sm-3 align-centre">

                @Html.Image(item.ByteImage, item.Name, "128")
                <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
                    <div class="item-container">

                        <div class="desc-plus-products">
                            <p>@item.Name</p>
                            <p>@item.Price</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

<div class="row whiteBG">
    <div class="see-all-image" onclick="SeeMoreProducts()">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/seeAll.jpg" alt="See all items :)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

> I am trying to add click functionality to my image div and have included an `onclick"SeeMoreProducts()" function`.

This is my JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function SeeMoreProducts() {
        $("#special-products:lt(5)").show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.slice` to achieve this and use `.on` event binding rather than `onClick` in html

```
var showItem = 5;  // Your desire number of item to show each time
var counter = 1;
$(function() {
  var $box = $('.blend-box');
  $box.slice(showItem).hide();
  $('.see-all-image').on('click', function() {
    $box.slice(0, showItem * counter + showItem).show();
    counter++;
  })
});
```

```js
var showItem = 5;  // Your desire number of item to show each time
var counter = 1;
$(function() {
  var $box = $('.blend-box');
  $box.slice(showItem).hide();
  $('.see-all-image').on('click', function() {
    console.log(showItem * counter + showItem);
    $box.slice(0, showItem * counter + showItem).show();
    counter++;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row whiteBG">

  <div id="special-products" class="col-sm-3 align-centre">
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blend-box category-head" style="background: #323232 url(@Html.ImageSrc(item.ByteImage)) no-repeat 50% 100%;">
      <div class="item-container">

        <div class="desc-plus-products">
          <p>@item.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Price</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row whiteBG">
  <div class="see-all-image" onclick="">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/seeAll.jpg" alt="See all items :)" />
  </div>
</div>
I am trying to add click functionality to my image div and have included an onclick"SeeMoreProducts()" function. This is my JS:
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Since my elements are being loaded one-by-one in a for-loop, it only works with my first element loaded. So when I change showItem to '0', and the second parameter of $box.slice to '2', the button works for showing the first element. The other elements are all visible.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to make the parameter for the box variable be assigned to my id, var $box = $('#special-products'); - but I realise this won't allow the JavaScript to be applied to multiple elements since that what classes are for. Thanks again Parvez! How do I become better at JavaScript?

Comment: @aladdin786 just be brave.